# Not able to click on WebElement

Tags: java, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In selenium I am getting  web element which i want to select `WebElement.IsDisplayed()` return `true`
but i am not able to perform `webelement.click()` operation.

```
 port_dimension = canvas.find( By.xpath( "//*[local-name() = 'rect'][@visibility='visible' and @height = '22']" ) ); //$NON-NLS-1$
 port_dimension.getElement().click();
```

Comment: Here in this code port_dimension.getElement() returns WebElement.

Comment: Can you please add the relevant HTML snippet ?

Comment: What language is this? It's not Java but you are using the Java tag. There are no `.find()` or `.getElement()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can also click on the `WebElement` without using `getElement()` function. Here's how -

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'rect'][@visibility='visible' and @height = '22']")).click();
```

If your xpath locator is working as required then the element should be clicked. If you still are getting some issue, then probably add a sleep event with `Thread.sleep(5000);` before click action. Hope this helps.

Comment: @AvinashJadhav let me know what error you are getting and also can you create a gist of your html file or paste it in your question?

Comment: actually nothing error coming but i could not able to select that element

Comment: @AvinashJadhav So then there might be an issue with your element locator. Can you update your html code so that we can suggest you to check with proper locator?

Comment: <rect stroke-dasharray="" vector-effect="" height="22" width="22" y="0" x="0" visibility="visible" stroke-width="1" fill="rgba(255,255,255,255)" 
    stroke="rgba(0,0,0,255)" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 169 -11)"></rect>

Answer (score 1):

You can also click using JavascriptExecutor

```
  WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[local-name() = 'rect'][@visibility='visible' and @height = '22']"));
  JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
  executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Now I am predicting the your xpath is fine and In some cases wait is needed so put wait if you are still facing issue. so

njoy ... get back to me if still facing issue :)